# load_from_checkpoint fails after transfer learning a LightningModule

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, pytorch-lightning

I try to transfer learn a LightningModule. The relevant part of the code is this:

```py
class DeepFilteringTransferLearning(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, chk_path = None):
        super().__init__()
        
        #init class members
        self.prediction = []
        self.label = []
        self.loss = MSELoss()
        
        #init pretrained model
        self.chk_path = chk_path
        model = DeepFiltering.load_from_checkpoint(chk_path)
        backbone = model.sequential
        layers = list(backbone.children())[:-1]
        self.groundModel = Sequential(*layers)
        
        #use the pretrained modell the same way to regress Lshall and neq
        self.regressor = nn.Linear(64,2)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.groundModel.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            groundOut = self.groundModel(x)
        yPred = self.regressor(groundOut)
        return yPred
```

I save my model in a different, main file which relevant part is:

```py
#callbacks
callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint(
            dirpath = "checkpoints/maxPooling16StandardizedL2RegularizedReproduceableSeeded42Ampl1ConvTransferLearned",
            save_top_k=5,
            monitor="val_loss",
        ),
    ]

#trainer
trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=[1,2],strategy="dp",max_epochs=150,logger=wandb_logger,callbacks=callbacks,precision=32,deterministic=True)
trainer.fit(model,train_dataloaders=trainDl,val_dataloaders=valDl)
```

After try to load the modell from checkpoint like this:

```py
chk_patH = "path/to/transfer_learned/model"
standardizedL2RegularizedL1 = DeepFilteringTransferLearning("path/to/model/trying/to/use/for/transfer_learning").load_from_checkpoint(chk_patH)
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _check_seekable(f)
    307     try:
--> 308         f.seek(f.tell())
    309         return True

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-13f5fd0c7b85> in <module>
      1 chk_patH = "checkpoints/maxPooling16StandardizedL2RegularizedReproduceableSeeded42Ampl1/epoch=4-step=349.ckpt"
----> 2 standardizedL2RegularizedL1 = DeepFilteringTransferLearning("checkpoints/maxPooling16StandardizedL2RegularizedReproduceableSeeded42Ampl2/epoch=145-step=10219.ckpt").load_from_checkpoint(chk_patH)

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py in load_from_checkpoint(cls, checkpoint_path, map_location, hparams_file, strict, **kwargs)
    154         checkpoint[cls.CHECKPOINT_HYPER_PARAMS_KEY].update(kwargs)
    155 
--> 156         model = cls._load_model_state(checkpoint, strict=strict, **kwargs)
    157         return model
    158 

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py in _load_model_state(cls, checkpoint, strict, **cls_kwargs_new)
    196             _cls_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in _cls_kwargs.items() if k in cls_init_args_name}
    197 
--> 198         model = cls(**_cls_kwargs)
    199 
    200         # give model a chance to load something

~/whistlerProject/gitHub/whistler/mathe/gwInspired/deepFilteringTransferLearning.py in __init__(self, chk_path)
     34         #init pretrained model
     35         self.chk_path = chk_path
---> 36         model = DeepFiltering.load_from_checkpoint(chk_path)
     37         backbone = model.sequential
     38         layers = list(backbone.children())[:-1]

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py in load_from_checkpoint(cls, checkpoint_path, map_location, hparams_file, strict, **kwargs)
    132                 checkpoint = pl_load(checkpoint_path, map_location=map_location)
    133             else:
--> 134                 checkpoint = pl_load(checkpoint_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
    135 
    136         if hparams_file is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/cloud_io.py in load(path_or_url, map_location)
     31     if not isinstance(path_or_url, (str, Path)):
     32         # any sort of BytesIO or similiar
---> 33         return torch.load(path_or_url, map_location=map_location)
     34     if str(path_or_url).startswith("http"):
     35         return torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(str(path_or_url), map_location=map_location)

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    579         pickle_load_args['encoding'] = 'utf-8'
    580 
--> 581     with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
    582         if _is_zipfile(opened_file):
    583             # The zipfile reader is going to advance the current file position.

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _open_file_like(name_or_buffer, mode)
    233             return _open_buffer_writer(name_or_buffer)
    234         elif 'r' in mode:
--> 235             return _open_buffer_reader(name_or_buffer)
    236         else:
    237             raise RuntimeError(f"Expected 'r' or 'w' in mode but got {mode}")

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in __init__(self, buffer)
    218     def __init__(self, buffer):
    219         super(_open_buffer_reader, self).__init__(buffer)
--> 220         _check_seekable(buffer)
    221 
    222 

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _check_seekable(f)
    309         return True
    310     except (io.UnsupportedOperation, AttributeError) as e:
--> 311         raise_err_msg(["seek", "tell"], e)
    312     return False
    313 

~/anaconda3/envs/skimageTrial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in raise_err_msg(patterns, e)
    302                                 + " Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and"
    303                                 + " try to load from it instead.")
--> 304                 raise type(e)(msg)
    305         raise e
    306 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
```

which I can't resolve.
I try to this according to the available tutorials on the official page of pytorch lightning [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/transfer_learning.html). I can't figure it out what I miss.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try as they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? `model = MyLightningModule.load_from_checkpoint(PATH)` Differences I notice: 1. They load outside of the class 2. You are loading some class which is named differently from yours, is this intended? 3. Please also show the code saving your checkpoint

Comment: @Gulzar I do not understand your link in this context. Moreover I do not understand 1.) either. They load inside the LightningModule `class CIFAR10Classifier(LightningModule):` a model from a different LightningModule `class AutoEncoder(LightningModule):` . 2.) I try to the same, loading a model from a different LightningModule `class DeepFiltering(pl.LightningModule):` to this LightningModule `class DeepFilteringTransferLearning(pl.LightningModule):`. 3.) I give it the snippet which I use to save my model and used pythonic syntax highlighting as you did in your edit.